# Can we create consumer tests and generate pact file without access to consumer code

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I am test automation engineer and new to PACT. My questions is I have a frontend and a backend. Frontend sends a request and get response from backend. I would like to create consumer tests and generate a Pact file, but I don't have access to the client code. Could someone tell me, if we can create consumer tests using java? Could you please also provide the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pact tests on the consumer side are a unit test of your API client, so it's not recommended to test from the outside of the code in a "black box" way. They really should be w

See [scope of a pact test](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/testing-scope#scope-of-a-consumer-pact-test) and [who would typically write Pact tests](https://docs.pact.io/faq/#who-would-typically-implement-pact).

You can do a form of black-box contract test using a feature in Pactflow called [bi-directional contracts](https://docs.pact.io/faq/#who-would-typically-implement-pact) (currently in developer preview), but note it's a commercial only feature.